# .NET GUI control library for an (audio) player

Tags: .net, user-interface, controls

I am going to build a player GUI control (a C# user control) for playing audio and other streamed data. The control should have at least the following controls:

- Pause/Continue/Forward/FastForward etc... as Buttons (with icons)
- Current position as some form of a slider
- Current time as digital clock

**Especially I am looking for a nice time slider control.**

**Do you know a library providing already pre-built such controls (preferably free)?**

*PS. I am aware that there are already questions for controls on StackOverflow, but none of them has a focus on player controls.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have used the Windows Media Player, embedded on my form. This works nice, except that I do not have much control of the actual visual representation.

This is how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx